# COUNTIF date occurs in same week number and year

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a bunch of dates in Column C, and then other dates in column J. How would I count the instances of dates in column C that fall in the same week number (and same year) as a date in a particular cell in column J?

Thanks for all help in advance

Comment: Countifs using a weeknumber function like IsoWeekNum and Year or sumproduct.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISOWEEKNUM(J1)=ISOWEEKNUM($C$1:$C$10)),--(YEAR(J1)=YEAR($C$1:$C$10)))
```

---

Data

[image: Data]

Comment: That's great thanks! Works exactly as needed, but for some reason takes a really long time to calculate? Any reason this might be?

Comment: How many rows are you calculating over? And what else do you have going on in the workbook calculation wise?

Comment: 100 rows, and that's all thats being calculated :(

Comment: It should be pretty much instantaneous. Sumproduct is designed for working with arrays. Maybe close workbook and open and try again.