# Count based on Week and Year for cells having Hyphens "-"

Tags: excel-formula, countif, week-number

I have a tasks tracking sheet and want to count number of tasks received based on week number for a particular year. Thanks for the post [COUNTIF date occurs in same week number and year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679434/countif-date-occurs-in-same-week-number-and-year)

But still i have problem that i have dates in a column where many of the cells are non-empty and filled with Hyphens "-". If i delete Hyphens, formula working fine. But i need to keep "-" in cells where date not entered.

Initially i tried 'Sumproduct' funtion, it shows #Value error because of Hyphen in cells. And i added the code `--(Task_Status!$X$7:$X$250<>"-")`. But still it showing same error. In my formula, where `Q2` is weeknumber 1 to 58 in a rage of cells Q2 to BQ2, that i have to copy(drag) the formula from Q3 to BQ3. And `$C$3` is cell having 4 digit Year (E.g. 2019). Please help...
A image here-->[Received&Completed_CW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgNwm.jpg)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISOWEEKNUM(Task_Status!$X$7:$X$250)=Q2),--(YEAR(Task_Status!$X$7:$X$250)=$C$3),--(Task_Status!$X$7:$X$250<>"-"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perfect i found a temporary formula... Its working fine if non-hyphen "-" exist until end of cell range specified by `INDIRECT` function...

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISOWEEKNUM(INDIRECT("Task_Status!$X$7:$X"&COUNTIFS(Task_Status!$X$7:$X$250,"<>-")+6,TRUE))=Q2),--(YEAR(INDIRECT("Task_Status!$X$7:$X"&COUNTIFS(Task_Status!$X$7:$X$250,"<>-")+6,TRUE))=$C$3))`

Please give a better solution than this if anyone found... Because still Hyphen present between start cell `X7` and end of cell range specified by `INDIRECT` function give no result... still need help...

Thank you for all who tried for a solution... and thanks to post [Excel Define a range based on a cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822536/excel-define-a-range-based-on-a-cell-value) and [Using the value in a cell as a cell reference in a formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150861/using-the-value-in-a-cell-as-a-cell-reference-in-a-formula)